# Unwind segue moves me to wrong view controller

Tags: ios, swift, segue, unwind-segue

In my test application I have two view controllers(VC1 and VC2) embedded in tab bar controller. Each view controller have "Jump" button, which move us to third view controller (VC3):

[image: my storyboard]

In VC1 I added function

```
@IBAction func unwindFromVC3(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    print("Unwind from VC3")
}
```

and connected "Save" bar item of VC3 with "Exit" icon for VC3.

So when I run my app and click "Jump" button of VC1 I moved to VC3, and when I click "Save", I moved back to VC1. That's ok.

If I move to VC2 bar and click "Jump" from there, I moved to VC3 again. But if I click "Save" from there I moved back to VC1 (not VC3) again.

I expected nothing happens there (because I don't have any "unwind" functions in VC2). So why I was moved to VC1? Is it possible to create two unwind actions for my "Save" item?

Comment: What do you want to happen when user transitions from VC2->VC3 and then hits "Save"?

Comment: In real app user will be able edit some object details in VC3. So when user click Save, details should be saved and user will be returned back to VC2.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to unwind back to VC2 from VC3, simply add `unwindFromVC3` to VC2 as well:

```
@IBAction func unwindFromVC3(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    print("Unwind from VC3")
}
```

Then the unwind segue will unwind to the correct ViewController (the one that segued to VC3).

You only have to set up the unwind segue once, and as long as all ViewControllers that transition to VC3 implement `unwindFromVC3`, the save will return to the originating ViewController.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you!