# Xcode: How to know the viewController that has presented the current view?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, tvos

I have two viewControllers "**FirstViewController**"&"**SecondViewControler**" that contain a button that presents a new viewController called "**BibliothequesViewController**" when a button is clicked:

```
@IBAction func onLibrariesButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc: BibliothequesViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BibliothequesViewController") as! BibliothequesViewController
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

For the time being, the  **BibliothequesViewController** contains a button that's redirects to the **FirstViewController** with a Segue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
           print("SegWay being performed")
           // Every segway has a beginning point and ending point
           // We're trying to access the ending point
           // as type FullScreenMovieController
           // Then we're setting the chosenMovie variable of FullScreenMovieController to 1
           let vc = segue.destination as! FirstViewController
           vc.receivedSelectedLibraryFromBibliothequesList = self.selectedLibrary
           print("vc.receivedSelectedLibraryFromBibliothequesList :",  vc.receivedSelectedLibraryFromBibliothequesList )
                }
```

This is the code that performs the Segue:

```
  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "BiblioToLoginSegue", sender: self)
```

**What I need to implement is:**
Redirect to the view (**FirstViewController** or **SecondViewControler**) that actually presented **BibliothequesViewController**.
The code above automatically redirects to **FirstViewController** whether it was the one that presented **BibliothequesViewController** or not.

I don't see which approach should I follow to implement this.
Should I use push instead of present in the **FirstViewController**&**SecondViewControler**?

Comment: I think you need an [unwind segue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12561735/1630618)

Comment: This should be helpful as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/36599319/1630618

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to teach a class to know something is to add a property:

```
class BibliothequesViewController {
    ...
    var presentedBy: UIViewController?
    ...
}
```

to assign the property after the controller instantiation

```
let vc: BibliothequesViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BibliothequesViewController") as! BibliothequesViewController

vc.presentedBy = self
```

and to use this property when the time comes.

Comment: presentedBy should contain FirstViewController or SecondViewController, that way BibliothequesViewController will know which one presented it. So you answer is right in the beginning but I think the second part is wrong.

Comment: I took your advice and tried this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63742725/setting-a-viewcontroller-property-by-using-a-shared-instance-remains-nil check it out if you can and tell me what you think

Comment: I just implemented a solution with your tip. Thank you. Check it out if you can .

Answer (score 0):

I took @Roman's advice but I changed a couple of things.
**CAVEAT:** I am not sure this is the right approach but it worked for me.

> BibliothequesViewController

```
class BibliothequesViewController: UIViewController {
    
    static let sharedInstance = BibliothequesViewController()
    var presentedBy: UIViewController?
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if BibliothequesViewController.sharedInstance.presentedBy! is LoginViewController {
            let vc = segue.destination as! LoginViewController
            vc.receivedSelectedLibraryFromBibliothequesList = self.selectedLibrary
        } else {
            let vc = segue.destination as! ForgetPasswordViewController
            vc.receivedSelectedLibraryFromBibliothequesList = self.selectedLibrary
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func onLibrarySelected(_ sender: Any) {
        if BibliothequesViewController.sharedInstance.presentedBy! is LoginViewController {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "BiblioToLoginSegue", sender: self)
        } else {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "biblioToPasswordForgottenSigue", sender: self)
        }
    }
    
}
```

> LoginViewController

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func onLibrariesButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc: BibliothequesViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BibliothequesViewController") as! BibliothequesViewController
        BibliothequesViewController.sharedInstance.presentedBy=self
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

> ForgetPasswordViewController

```
  class ForgetPasswordViewController: UIViewController {
        @IBAction func onLibrariesButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
            let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc: BibliothequesViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BibliothequesViewController") as! BibliothequesViewController
            BibliothequesViewController.sharedInstance.presentedBy=self
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

**NOTE:** You have to create two Segues from **BibliothequesViewController** to **LoginViewController** and **ForgetPasswordViewController** with the identifiers mentioned in **BibliothequesViewController**.