# Setting a viewController property by using a shared instance remains nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, tvos

I have two viewControllers:
**1/ LoginViewController**
**2/ BibliothequeViewController**

I am presenting **BibliothequeViewController** by clicking on a button inside **LoginViewController** and in the same time trying to communicate to **BibliothequeViewController** that it was **LoginViewController** that presented it.

So inside **LoginViewController**, I have this:

```
  @IBAction func onLibrariesButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc: BibliothequesViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BibliothequesViewController") as! BibliothequesViewController
        BibliothequesViewController.sharedInstance.presentedBy=self
        print("INSIDE LoginViewController.onLibrariesButtonClicked, BibliothequesViewController.sharedInstance.presentedBy",BibliothequesViewController.sharedInstance.presentedBy!)
        // Logs LoginViewController
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Inside **BibliothequesViewController**, I have this:

```
class BibliothequesViewController: UIViewController {
    // presentedBy represents which view has presented the BibliothequesViewController
    // So that when a library is selected, I go back to the ViewController that presented BibliothequesViewController
    var presentedBy: UIViewController?
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       print("INSIDE viewDidLoad, presentedBy: ",presentedBy) 
       // Logs nil
    }
  }
```

So as you see, in the **LoginViewController** code, `BibliothequesViewController.sharedInstance.presentedBy` has been set to **LoginViewController**.

But inside **BibliothequeViewController**, it is `nil`, when it should be **LoginViewController**.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
 print("INSIDE BibliothequesViewController, BibliothequesViewController.sharedInstance.presentedBy",BibliothequesViewController.sharedInstance.presentedBy!)
```

And I got **LoginViewController** logged. So I got what I needed.

But I expected the code above to work too.